# Find LDAP Groups and Member emails

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap, ldap-query

I am trying to search for All Groups and Members under a specific OU in my Active Directory.

The below query works fine.

```
ldapsearch -o ldif-wrap=no -b OU=BUSINESS_DOMAIN,OU=ONE,DC=myserver,DC=com -s one '(cn=*)' member cn
```

I can get the group names and member names(CN) from the AD. But is there a way to get the member emails as well?

Should I iterate over each member and trigger a separate LDAP Search programmatically or can I create a chained query?

**EDIT**

Based on the comments, adding more clarity- I am looking for email id of all users  embedded under groups under a given OU.

Comment: Please try to explain a bit more in detail what you want to achieve. Do you want to have e-mail address lists by group?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
ldapsearch -o ldif-wrap=no -b OU=BUSINESS_DOMAIN,OU=ONE,DC=myserver,DC=com -s one '(cn=*)' member cn mail
```

Assuming you are using the LDAP standard email address attribute "mail" for the email address.

Comment: Your _ldapsearch_ command simply returns attributes _member_, _cn_ and _mail_ for every direct subordinate entry of _OU=BUSINESS_DOMAIN,OU=ONE,DC=myserver,DC=com_ which contains attribute _cn_. From my understanding that's not what was asked because at least it also returns search results of entries which are not members of any group.

Comment: Guess we need clarification as to what he really wants. Users that are within an OU or user that are embers within Groups within an OU? Or both?

Comment: Yes. That's why I also added a comment to the question.